# argument concatenation in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, dom, scripting

The example is from the book "dom scripting" - jeremy keith.

```
function moveElement(elementID,final_x,final_y,interval) { 
if (!document.getElementById) return false; 
if (!document.getElementById(elementID)) return false; 
var elem = document.getElementById(elementID); 
var xpos = parseInt(elem.style.left); 
var ypos = parseInt(elem.style.top); 
if (xpos == final_x && ypos == final_y) { 
return true; 
} 
if (xpos < final_x) { 
xpos++; 
} 
if (xpos > final_x) { 
xpos--; 
} 
if (ypos < final_y) { 
ypos++; 
} 
if (ypos > final_y) { 
ypos--; 
} 
elem.style.left = xpos + "px"; 
elem.style.top = ypos + "px"; 
var repeat = "moveElement('"+elementID+"',"+final_x+","+final_y+","+interval+")"; 
movement = setTimeout(repeat,interval);
}
```

I don't understand why there's so many concatenation in this line

```
var repeat = "moveElement('"+elementID+"',"+final_x+","+final_y+","+interval+")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `var repeat` is actually a string representation of a function call, rather than a function itself.

To do the same thing in code (not using a string) you'd do something like this:

```
    var repeat = function() { moveElement(elementId, final_x, final_y, interval); }
    movement = setTimeout(repeat, interval);
```

Comment: why not -  movement =setTimeout("moveElement(elementId, final_x, final_y, interval)",interval);

Comment: You shouldn't do that because you are passing the names of the variables rather than the data they contain. On top of that, passing a string representation of a function isn't good code practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is just weird way to call function. You should never use string as first argument of setTimeout and setInterval, and I would not recommend to read book with this kind of examples.

Correct way is to pass anonimous function with desired function call.

Comment: Sorry, I never read books about dom scripting, so I don't know good ones. My way to learn how to code was always reading and writing code not books. You might want to start from best practices and coding style, as they are usually essential of many smart programmers experience. The best way to learn how to code is reading and contributing to opensource code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `repeat` contains call of `moveElement` function. As we know arguments passing to function must be separated by `,`. So here we concatenate values of variables with coma to get the string which will call function `moveElement`